# Wrapping objective-c classes into c++ classes: best practices?

Tags: c++, objective-c, wrapper

I have a c++ class implemented in a objective-c++ (.mm) file. 
This class contains some Cocoa object, say a `NSToolbar`, as a (private) member variable.
The class should be exposed as a pure c++ interface and usable by pure c++ clients.
In other words, I am trying to wrap obj-c objects in a c++ class.

The first thing that crosses my mind is to use a void pointer in the class interface
and then work around with casting within the class implementation, whenever `_toolbar` needs to be treated as a `NSToolbar`.

For example I would have the interface:

```
// NSToolbarWrapper.h
class NSToolbarWrapper {
private:
void * _toolbar;

//... rest of the class ...

}
```

and the implementation:

```
// NSToolbarWrapper.mm
...
ToolbarWrapper::ToolbarWrapper (...){
_toolbar = (__bridge void *)[[NSToolbar alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"My toolbar!"];
...
}
```

I am not sure this is the smartest approach.
Is there a best practice in this case?

Comment: I have found the best approach is to use the pimpl idiom when declaring the class that will be exposed to pure c++

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pimpl idiom with c++ interface and objective c++ implementation.
You'll need to declare your destructor and define it in the .mm file if you use unique_ptr as your pimpl;

class.h:

```
class myclass {
    class impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> _impl; // or shared_ptr if you want shared handle behaviour

public:
    myclass(const char* s);
    ~myclass(); // only declare here
};
```

class.mm:

```
class myclass::impl {
    NSString* _str;
public:
    impl(const char* s) 
    : _str([NSString stringWithCString:s encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]) 
    {}
};

myclass::myclass(const char* s)
: _impl(new impl(s))
{}

myclass::~myclass() = default;  // define here
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of documentation, and to remind myself in the future.

I have seen a pretty well-known open source library doing like this, which also seems to be a valid approach:

```
// NSToolbarWrapper.h
#ifdef __OBJC__
typedef NSToolbar *Toolbar;
#else
typedef class NSToolbar_opaque *Toolbar;
#endif // __OBJC__

class NSToolbarWrapper {
private:
Toolbar _toolbar;

//... rest of the class ...

}
```